# RTMP link youtube

Tags: youtube, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

im having issues to provide a rtmp link of my live webcast.

I need to send my rtmp link to another person im using this format [rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/Name_webcast](http://rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/Name_webcast)
But this doesn't work, i tried on vlc without luck.
I don't know if that link is for input, i need the output, so anyone can re-stream my live webcast.

Does anyone know how to get the link of the rtmp youtube webcast? 
I'm getting the links from youtube settings.

Answer (score 0):

The `RTMP` URL provided by YouTube is used for *ingestion* and not playback. For playback the platform offers multiple formats, depending on your device/browser. The content is meant to be viewed via YouTube so the streams are not exposed.

Comment: ok, so i can't provide a tv channel a rtmp link for them. Didn't know that, thanks aergistal

Comment: You could install a RTMP server and set it up so it pushes to YouTube and lets the other client pull.